# Why $ \int_{X} f d\mu >0 \Leftrightarrow \mu({\{x\in X \mid f(x)>0}\})>0$ when (X,M,$\mu$) a measure space, $f:X\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Here is an excercise of measure theory and real analysis. can you help me with it?

> Let (X,M,$\mu$) be a measure space and $f:X\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ a measurable function. Prove that $$ \int_{X} f d\mu >0  \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad \mu\big({\{x\in X \mid f(x)>0}\}\big)>0.$$

I tried to use the definition of the integral by the approximation theorem of measurable functions by simple functions, but I haven't been able to come to the conclusion.

Comment: Since $f(x) \geq 0$, you should be able to partition $X$ into the part where $f(x) = 0$ and the part where $f(x) > 0$ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=\{x\mid f(x)>0\}$ and $A_{n}=\{x\mid f(x)>\frac{1}{n}\}$.
Note that $A=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}$. If $\mu(A)>0$, then $\mu(A_{n})>0$
for some $n$. Therefore $\int f\geq\int_{A_{n}}f\geq\frac{1}{n}\mu(A_{n})>0$.

Conversely, suppose that $\int f>0$. Denote $B=\{x\mid f(x)=0\}$.
We have that $\int f=\int_{A}f+\int_{B}f=\int_{A}f$. If $\mu(A)=0$,
then $\int_{A}f=0$ and we arrive a contradiction. Therefore $\mu(A)>0$.
(By definition, $\int_{A}f=\int1_{A}f$ and the integrand $1_{A}f=0$
a.e. if $\mu(A)=0$. I hope that you would not ask me to prove that $\int g=0$ whenever
$g=0$ a.e.)